# How can I add an emoji as status on JDA 4?

Tags: java, discord, bots

I'm currently working on a Discord Bot, and I'm using JDA 4. I wanted to ask how I can add an emoji at the bot activity or status. I read the documentation and found out, that you can use `Activity.Emoji(String name, long id, boolean animated)` to specify an emote. However, I don't know how to implement it to my activity.

Here is the source code that I'm using right now:

```
JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(Config.TOKEN);
builder.setActivity(Activity.playing("Some text"));
jda = builder.build();
```

I hope somebody can help me, because I haven't found any answers on the internet yet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's possible for bots to have a custom status with an emoji as you can set right now by being a user.

Comment: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1160